# In Unison's UCM, is there a way to display a diff before running update?

Tags: unison-lang

This would basically be analogous to `git diff`. I see there are namespace diffing commands for things already committed to a Unison code base, but I may have missed how to do a diff prior to updating, if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present, there isn't a way to get a line-by-line diff of your work-in-progress in a scratch file with already added content of a namespace. You can see which terms and functions would be changed with the `update.preview` command and then `view 1-n` of the terms listed there in the console to see the last saved state of your code, but that command alone won't give a content breakdown.

The `fork`, `update`, then `merge` workflow for adding a feature might provide a lightweight way of viewing incremental changes without polluting your original namespace.

To do this, `fork` your original namespace to a `myWIP` namespace, then `update` your changes in this namespace. You can use the namespace diffing and `view` source tools between your original namespace and this `myWIP` one to see changes. Once you're done you can `merge` your namespace back into the original one and delete ones you don't need.

Comment: I ended up using `diff.namespace` (in place of view tools), followed by `delete.namespace` to remove the WIP namespace, as that seemed to be a straightforward path.